# iOS WKWebView displays sometimes

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a web page link that will not display via iOS `WKWebView`. How do I get links like this to display via `WKWebView`?

It appears that only 3 version of https://www.google.com and http://www.apple.com will display a Web page using http:// or https://. How do I get the other web pages to load via WKWebView? (note: all of the web sites load inside of Google Chrome and Apple Safari without using the http:// syntax.)

Below is the code from ViewDidLoad:

```
          @IBOutlet weak var myWebkitView: WKWebView!
          override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()


        `if let myUrl = URL(string:"https://www.ihs-us.org")`
         {

          let myURLRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
          myWebkitView.load(myURLRequest)

         }

         }

      Below links works only for Apple and Google. 
     https://www.google.com will shows a Web site
     http://www.apple.com also will shows its web site
     schools.nyc.gov/SchoolPortals/08/X282 -- causes a crash
     ihs-us.org // causes a crash, and does not show a web page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this** -

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = "ihs-us.org"

        if urlString.hasPrefix("https://") || urlString.hasPrefix("http://"){
            let myURL = URL(string: urlString)
            let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
            webView.load(myRequest)
        }else {
            let correctedURL = "http://\(urlString)"
            let myURL = URL(string: correctedURL)
            let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
            webView.load(myRequest)
        }

    }

}
```

For [schools.nyc.gov/SchoolPortals/08/X282](http://schools.nyc.gov/SchoolPortals/08/X282) -

[image]

And for [ihs-us.org](http://ihs-us.org) -

[image]

You just need to do the following steps-

Open your `Info.plist` file of your project. Right click on it and add a row.

[image]

And after that just add those two lines in your (as it is) -

[image: Info.plist]`

Comment: Thank you for those images! I copied, and pasted your code into my Xcode project, and the Web sites that only loaded were google.com, apple.com, and www.apple.com. When I used let urlString = "ihs-us.org", the web page does not load.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers append http:// to the url(if not present) and usually if a web page supports SSL, there will be a re-direction to https:// site. I developed a browser for internal use and any URL user enters, I append http:// to the URL. The simplest way would be

```
class func getValidURLFromString(_ urlString: String)->String{        
    if !urlString.hasPrefix("http://") && !urlString.hasPrefix("https://"){
        return "http://" + urlString
    }
    else {
        return urlString
    }
}
```

**Edited:**
ViewController Code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let urlString = isValidURLFormat("schools.nyc.gov/SchoolPortals/08/X282")
    let myURL = URL(string: urlString)
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}
func isValidURLFormat(_ urlString: String) -> String {
    if !urlString.hasPrefix("https://") && !urlString.hasPrefix("http://"){
        return "http://" + urlString
    }
    return urlString }
```

}

**Plist Setting**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: I used a slight variation of your code, and the web site will still only load for www.apple.com, google.com, and apple.com. Below is the code that I am currently using ...

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let urlString = isValidURLFormat("schools.nyc.gov/SchoolPortals/08/X282")
        
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
}        
    func isValidURLFormat(_ urlString: String) -> String {
        if !urlString.hasPrefix("https://") || !urlString.hasPrefix("http://"){
             return "http://" + urlString
        }
        return urlString
    }

Comment: @MikeIOSMike i have updated the working code. the plist settings are also required.